# How to save Dicom Image with dicom format after anonymization?

Tags: pydicom

- I read a dicom image with all metadate, and anonymized some fields, I want to write it again after that, but I get the error: `if None in (dataset.is_little_endian, dataset.is_implicit_VR):
  AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'is_little_endian'`
- I read the [documentation of pydicom](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/reference/fileio.write.html), but didn't understand how to do it!
- How can I write it again in one working instruction ?
- Edit: Birthdate changed to `None` instead of `'None'`, and `dcmwrite` insted of `save_as`.

```
import pydicom
from pydicom.misc import is_dicom

fp ='1.dcm'
dico = pydicom.filereader.dcmread(fp)
if(is_dicom(dico)):
        dico['PatientID']= 'None'
        dico['PatientBirthDate'] = None
        dico['is_little_endian'] = True
        dico['is_implicit_VR'] = True
        path = '/dataset'
        # dico.save_as(os.path.join(path,'Anonymous.dcm'))
        pydicom.dcmwrite(os.path.join(path,'Anonymous.dcm'), dico)
```

Comment: Use `pydicom.dcmwrite(filename, dico)`. Besides, `"None"` is not a valid date - did you mean `None`?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I changed birthdate to `None`, and used `pydicom.dcmwrite(filename, dico)`, and got the following error : `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'is_little_endian'`

Comment: Ah yes, you have to set `is_little_endian` and `is_implicite` in the dataset. Should be in the documentation somewhere, I can look this up later today (no time right now).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, using `save_as` should actually work, if you use it as in your first attempt. Here is the code that should work:

```
import pydicom
from pydicom.misc import is_dicom

dico = pydicom.filereader.dcmread('1.dcm')
dico.PatientID = 'None'
dico.PatientBirthDate = None
path = '/dataset'
dico.save_as(os.path.join(path,'Anonymous.dcm'))
# alternatively:
# dcmwrite(os.path.join(path,'Anonymous.dcm', dico)
```

Note that I have changed `dico['PatientID']` to `dico.PatientID`. This is not only a convenient shortcut, but also changes the semantics: if you assign to `dico['PatientID']`, you have to assign a `DataElement`:

```
dico['PatientID'] = DataElement(0x00100020, 'PN', b'None')
```

whereas if you use the keyword, you can directly assign the value (which is converted to a `DataElement` internally).

I agree that the documentation is somewhat lacking in that aspect - I think it would make sense to add a simple example for reading a DICOM file, modifying it, and writing it back. But if you check [the basic dataset documentation](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/tutorials/dataset_basics.html), you should find most of the needed information.

A note regarding the mentioned properties `is_little_endian` and `is_implicit_VR`: these are only needed if you write a new dataset that does not have a transfer syntax set. [Here](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/auto_examples/input_output/plot_write_dicom.html#write-dicom-data) is an example for that case. If the dataset is read from a valid DICOM file, it has these properties already set.

Comment: @mrbean-bermen `dico.save_as(os.path.join(path,'Anonymous.dcm'))`
`AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'save_as'`, after reading the dicom image it turns to be a dictionary, how can I convert it to FileDataset object again to be able to do `save_as`

Comment: This is strange - that should not happen. Which pydicom version do you use? And are you saying that `type(dico)` after assigning it says `dict`?

Comment: @MrBean-Bermen it worked now, thanks, I had copied the data from file to file so they had got converted, I will fix it, thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help :)